# Ubuntu 18.04 server on VPS. How to make .iso backup

Tags: server, backup, iso, vps

I have a VPS hosted on OVH.

Fortunately on SBG3 so my VPS is finally online.

I have made regularly backup of code and I have tutorial for reinstall everything.

I'm questioning about a full-system backup made in iso image to make sure that every configuration and every settings is correct.

I'm a web developer so I'm not an expert.

Can someone suggest to me the correct way to do this? Maybe a fast one?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Well my personal opinion is that backing up an entire vps just for a webapp is a waste of time. Let's say you want to do that, you will need the same amount of free space as your vps drive then use a command like dd to copy an exact image of the drive, if you try to do this on the actual vps you'll run out of space.
scenario 2: Backup only relevant data and programs, copy your programs folders in /etc/ and /var/lib whatever and then recover if something happens.
Scenario 3: use docker for your webapp, that way you can install whatever you need freeze the image only backup the image and whenever you need to replicate just load it and in matters of minutes you will have your service up and running again.